Android 12 X55 missing widget
I have a X55 android version 12 I lost my widgets when I had to do a factory reset, is that why? It never happened before.

Looks like there are a few brands having model name X55: XMobile (phone), PoE (TV), Redmi (TV), StarSat (TV). Could you clarify the brand?

Performing a factory reset will delete all data on the device, including the placement of your widgets on your home screen. You can replace your widgets pressing and holding on a blank spot on the home screen and tapping "Widgets"
If you mean that widgets that you had before the factory reset are not available in the "Widgets" menu, then you must reinstall the app that provided that widget. Widgets all come from installed apps. Because a factory reset removes all non-system apps, it will also remove all non-system widgets being provided by those apps. Just re-install the app(s) that provided you with the widget(s) you used, and you should be good to go.

The widget I think you are referring to usually comes from the Google Clock App and looks like this:


Aren't widgets pre-programmed into the phone? I haven't had to install an app for them. I've done factory resets on other phones and the widgets were still available. Well thank you for your help have a nice day.

@GayleHollister Certain widgets come from apps that are pre-installed on your phone (system apps). These system apps stay after a reset (with cleared data) because they are needed for the device to work, so their widgets stay too. Maybe if you can edit your question to add the specific widget you're looking for, I can help with some specifics?

I'm missing the digital clock with day and date. Thank you for your help. Have a great day.

@GayleHollister I've edited my answer for your specific widget. I also recommend you edit your question to include the specific widget you were looking for to help others who may come across your question in the future. Glad I could help!

Yes that's the widget I'm missing. Do I need to install it? I thought it was pre-programmed into the phone.

@GayleHollister The clock app is usually pre-installed, though it may have been uninstalled after a factory reset. If you reinstall it from the link in the post, it should work again.

Ok thank you for your help. Take care and happy holidays.
